# cgal:surface simplification and keep texture map

Tags: cgal, simplification

I would like to use the surface simplification algorithm of CGAL with wavefront object.

I can get a good result by using the `edge_collapse` function. But my 3D models have texture maps, I can't use the original texture map information for the reduced models.

So how can I map the original texture map information to the reduced model?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a property map vertex-UV that you fill with your full Mesh. Once it has been simplified, the remaining vertices will still have their original UVs in the property map.